# Does window.onload guarantee that jQuery will be defined?

Tags: jquery, node.js, onload, ejs

I have the following setup:

**header.ejs**

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
        <link href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
```

**page.ejs**

```
<%- include ../partials/header -%>

<!-- some HTML code -->

<script>
// error: $ is not defined
$(function () { });

window.onload = function () {
    // $ is defined
}
</script>

<%- include ../partials/footer -%>
```

**footer.ejs**

```
        <script src="/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Currently, the inline JS code only works when I use `window.onload`. Without it, an error message `$ is not defined` appears in my console. I understand that the code must be placed after the jquery script tag in the `footer.ejs` for it to work.

My question is does using `window.onload` as shown in my example guarantee that jQuery will be defined in its callback? Is it possible for jQuery to be `undefined` when `window.onload` gets fired?

Comment: Taken from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload), `The load event fires at the end of the document loading process. At this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all the images, scripts, links and sub-frames have finished loading.`

Comment: @choz Thanks, your comment seems to answer my question unlike the answers given.

Answer (score -1):

If you'd like to guarantee jQuery is loaded before executing anything, wrap your JS in jQuery's document ready method:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  // Run your jQuery here...
});
```

Any JS run in that block will only be called once jQuery is requested, loaded, and executed in browser.

Comment: This will only work if the block of code is placed after the jQuery script tag in the footer. Otherwise, `jQuery is not defined`. Anyways, choz's comment seems to answer my question. Thanks tho.